# Entity Framework - relationship with fake Foreign Key (no foreign key in the db)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I have many tables that have TextID column which refers to the translation table. Translation table needs also LanguageID to get translated text in desired language. My problem is that I do not have LanguageID in my database, it is predefined in the system and I do not know how can I define it using Fluent API, i.e this can be my model:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{    
    public short ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TextID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Nullable<int> LanguageID { get; set; }
    public virtual TEXT_TRANSLATION Translation { get; set; }
}
```

And the translation table:

```
public partial class TEXT_TRANSLATION
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int TextID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }

    public string TranslatedText { get; set; } 
}
```

Basically I need navigation like this:

```
myEntity.Translation.TranslatedText
```

While using SQL, I would do it like this:

```
Left Join TEXT_TRANSLATION ON 
  MyEntity.TextID = TEXT_TRANSLATION.TextID 
  AND TEXT_TRANSLATION.LanguageID = 1033
```

Basically I want to use TextID foreign key and get **ONLY ONE** translation - LanguageID is static and predefined in context.

I can't change existing DB schema. It would be perfect if I won't need to map LanguageID field in my code, just use it inside mapping like a system parameter. Is it even possible with EF?

Comment: But you already have a column LanguageID in TEXT_TRANSLATION table, don't you ?

Comment: yes, but i do not have LanguageId in the other table. And i need this navigation

Comment: And can user make modifications to TEXT_TRANSLATION table ? Is it a huge table ? Cause you might get all its content, put it in a static list, and work with it, maybe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `LanguageID` is static you can try to use this hack.

Define your entities like:

```
public class Entity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TextId { get; set; }
    public Translation Translation { get; set; }
}

// No LanguageId in translation
public class Translation {
    public int TextId { get; set; }
    public string TranslatedText { get; set; }
}
```

And add this fluent mapping to `OnModelCreating` in your derived `DbContext`:

```
// Define foreign key
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Translation)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.TextId);

// Trick - EF believes that only TextId is PK. Without this trick you cannot
// make navigation property on your entity
modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>()
            .HasKey(t => t.TextId);

// If you are going to insert translations as well your TextId cannot be 
// handled as autogenerated column
modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>()
            .Property(t => t.TextId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

// The HACK - conditional mapping. This tells EF to "see" only records
// with LanguageId set to 1033. Without this hack you cannot filter 
// translations for only single language.
modelBuilder.Entity<Translation>()
            .Map(m => {
                        m.Requires("LanguageId").HasValue(1033);
                        m.ToTable("Translations");   
                    });
```

The hack is based on concept used for TPH mapping but in this case you are only using single entity type to load only subset of records with predefined `LanguageId`. Even FK from the main entity should work because you cannot have to translations with the same `TextId` - it would mean that they also have the same `LanguageId` which is not possible because `TextId` and `LanguageId` form primary key.

I'm not sure if there is any hidden issue in this solution. I just gave it a quick try and it worked.

Comment: Great! It really works :)
Is it possible to make this .HasValue dynamic ? I mean dynamic for new context, so every user can have his own languageid?

Comment: @Jarek: The answer is both yes and no. In the normal way it is not possible because the value is part of the mapping. Mapping is "compiled" only once when the context is used for the first time and then reused = every context instance will have the same language. If you want to use multiple languages you must manually handle that compilation, cache your compiled models and provide compiled model to your context constructor - look for DbContext's constructor accepting `DbCompiledModel`.

Comment: I think I owe you a beer :)

Comment: It works fine, but I can't update record with this languageid. It updates all records with the same textid, even if they have different languageid.

Comment: I thought there will be some side effect. It makes sense. EF updates records by their mapped primary key but we have mapped only half of it. I'm afraid you will need to execute direct SQL for updates if you want to continue using this approach.

Comment: I've had to create derivative models where they were based on a core base "dbContext". What worked for me was to create sub-types, where each one extended the base "dbContext" and the specific OnModelCreating for that sub-type had the specifics in it peculiar to that model. In my case, the OnModelCreating actually changed the table-names that the Entities in the core model mapped to. But, I bet it would work to have sub-types like "dbContextEnglish", "dbContextSpanish", etc that would support specific language IDs

Answer (score 2):

What if you did something like this:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{    
    public short ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TextID { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Nullable<int> LanguageID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TEXT_TRANSLATION> Transations {get;set;}

    public IQueryable<TEXT_TRANSLATION> Translation
    {
      get
      {
          return this.Translations.Where( t => t.LanguageID == this.LanguageID );
      }
    }
}
```

The virtual ICollection would store a list of all your translations regardless of language, and the Translation property would do the .Where() for you

Comment: You can't have a navigation property (the virtual ICollection in your sample) if the relations are not correct. They are many identical TextID in TEXT_TRANSLATION table, so I'm almost certain that EF will shout loudly !

Comment: MyEntity can have multiple translations and translations can have multiple MyEntities?  Sounds like you should have EF generate a join table mapping TextId to MyEntity.Id - then this solution would work fine.

Comment: But EF can't manage the relation (PK / FK) as MyEntity has not LanguageID column in the database. And TEXT_TRANSLATION has a composite key. I would be really surprised if it was possible to have a relation knowing only a part of a composite key...

Comment: and by the way "I can't change existing DB schema".

Answer (score 2):

Even if T_T table is huge, I don't see how you could do this another way (well, at least the need to "load all somewhere").

```
public static class Translator {
  private static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> translations_;

  static Translator() {
    translations_ = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>();
  } 

  public static void PopulateTranslator(Repository repo) {//or something to go to your db
     translations_ = repo.TEXT_TRANSLATIONs.ToList()
                     .GroupBy(m => m.LanguageId)
                     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                                   g=> g.ToDictionary(x => x.TextID,
                                                      x=> x.TranslatedText)
                                   );
  }
  public static string GetTranslation(int languageId, int? textId) {
      if (textId == null || !translations.ContainsKey(languageId)
         return something or throw;
      var dic = translations[languageId];
      var id = Convert.ToInt32(textId);
      if (!dic.ContainsKey(id)
          return something or throw;

      return dic[id);

  }
```

you would call `Translator.PopulateTranslator(<something to access your db>)` on start of your application, with maybe resettings, if users can update translations.

Then in your entities, instead of

```
public virtual TEXT_TRANSLATION Translation { get; set; }
```

you would have

```
public string TranslatedText {
    get { return Translator.GetTranslation(LanguageID, TextId);}
}
```

**EDIT**
Another way would be to work with resx files instead of db datas, but I imagine you have other constraints.